# Highstock rangeselector : How to check when the user has finished sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highstock chart and have other corresponding charts which are updated as per the Highstock selected values. I am using the afterSetExtremes method to know the final min and values. But every small slide is taken as a change (understandably) . Is there a way I can check when the user has finally stopped sliding and has selected a value? What I want is to ensure that the user has selected a value and then change the other charts. I am currently keeping track of mouseDown and mouseUp. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you can use events.selection to get exact start/end point

Comment: As long as [`scrollbar.liveRedraw`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#scrollbar.liveRedraw) is set to true you can not achieve that. I mean, with live redraw, extremes are called all the time, unless user stops playing with the chart. There is no separate `afterSetExtremes` for `mouseUp` event - when user releases mouse button, extremes are already set. With disabled `liveRedraw` you will have just one event, but smooth animation when panning the chart will be missing.